# File from non-active change list is modified

Tags: java, android, git, intellij-idea, gradle

I've opened my project in the morning and this line appeared in the `Gradle` app module.

There are three options : `Move changes`, `Save Changelist` and `Ignore`.

Does someone have an idea what's wrong and what I should do?

Comment: did tou solve this problem ? i have the same and some of my files are marked as non active, a don't know how to make them "active" . thankx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a open bug in IDEA regarding this issue:

> IDEA-51396 Tasks: if conflicted file is opened in 2 editor tabs, tasks toolbar actions (switch changelist/move changes/ignore) don't make toolbar disappear

It's the IDE behaviours and you don't have to worry about it at all.

Choose what options suits you the best and continue your work.

Comment: In the case that it is not the bug it is simply stating that changes have been made to files that are not under your current active git changelist

Answer (score 1):

It is related to source control of android studio. If you do not use inbuilt source control of studio just ignore it. If yes, then you can save the changelist and commit later.

Comment: I do use a src control, but why it is appeared today with no visible reason?